# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in Xamarin.Forms UWP (Windows) App when changing ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms app (.NET Standard 2.0, Xamarin.Forms 4.8), which so far I have only used for the Android project, which is working like a charm. I just reactivated the UWP (Universal Windows) project, though, which also compiles perfectly fine, but when I try to run it, the very first ObservableCollection I populate (triggered from the main page's OnAppearing) causes the mentioned exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
> HResult=0x8001010E
>
> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.
> [original message in German: Eine Schnittstelle, die für einen anderen Thread marshalled war, wurde von der Anwendung aufgerufen.]
> Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)

I generally know this type of error message (I run into them all the time in other projects ^^), as the update of the list doesn't happen on the UI thread, so the data binding is unhappy. Usually I'd wrap it in some dispatcher (my research has specifically suggested using `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync`). Except the code handling the actual list is of course in my separate View Model project (.NET Standard 2.0), which is supposed to be system agnostic (as it is also used by the Android project), and the mentioned dispatcher is Windows-specific, so this solution is kind of not available for me.

What can I do to solve this? Is there some kind of Xamarin or .NET Standard dispatcher I can use here? Or is there any other way to somehow modify, how the UWP app... does the data binding or something?!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread

Comment: That was embarrasingly easy... Could you please quickly post it as proper answer, so I can mark it as solution @Jason ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the Xamarin Essentials [MainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread) helper